# Python Apply Partial Lambda to List of Tuples

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I have a list of tuples, each tuple has about 20 elements. The basic data structure is as follows:

```
data[1]
>>('3824813',
    '310202',
    'AEOIME',
    'UEJNAJ',
    ...
    )
```

Some of these tuples contain undefined strings, in which case I want to exclude the containing tuple. So I used a `filter` like:

```
data2 = list(filter(lambda t: '' not in t, data))
```

Now things are slightly more complicated because I now learned that the 15th element of the tuple should still be kept, even if it's blank.

**My question is:** How can I write a filter that excludes all tuples from my list if they contain `''` in any element except for the 15th element?

The only thing I could think of was do a separate filter to find the empty 15th elements and combine them back in after I do the heavy filtering. To me that seems overly hacky, but that's just me. Either way, let me know what would work well here, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is write a filter function like this:

```
def keepTuple(tpl):
    for idx, string in enumerate(tpl):
       if idx == 14 and string == "":
           continue
       elif string == "":
           return False
    return True
```

Then, if I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to use this to filter your list:

```
data2 = list(filter(keepTuple, data))
```

I don't understand your data well enough, though. Can you have tuples where *more* than the 15th element is empty or can only one string in the tuple be empty?

Comment: more than 15th element could be empty

Comment: So, if any element *aside from* the 15th is empty, then you reject, but if *only* the 15th element is empty (or no element is empty), then you keep it?

Comment: yes that's right, if only the 15th element is empty then I want to keep that tuple (otherwise I reject). Cool idea by the way!

Comment: I have been doing some diagnostics, and for some weird reason there are some tuples containing empty elements that are still getting through. namely, the first error thrown is the 69th item of the list. On this tuple the 2nd index (aka 3rd element) was empty. My `data2[i][2] == ''` if statement was triggered, and I used `print()` to retrieve the details. It doesn't make sense though, your function seems like it should work.

Comment: maybe what's happening is the 15th element **and** the 2nd element are both empty. But even then, the function would handle that correctly, right? I'm confused.

Comment: @ArashHowaida there was a bad indentation: I fixed it. The `return True` part should only happen after the entire thing has been iterated (similar to what your `'' in tupl` test would perform).